# Having trouble translating Matlab fsolve into Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerics, code-review, matlab

I searched the site and found that someone said `FindRoot` is equivalent to `fsolve`, however, without proper options, `FindRoot` is going to run forever. In my case, I am trying to do the numerical approximations, but it seems that Mathematica is doing a lot of symbolic calculations.

Here is the original Matlab code I want to translate:

```
x0 = 0.06*ones(14,1);
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter','TolFun',1e-60,'TolX',1e-60);
[x1,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x0,options);
```

And my attempt is:

```
x1=FindRoot[myfun14[Array[x, 14]] == 0, Transpose[{Array[x, 14], ConstantArray[0.06, 14]}]]
```

Thanks!

The full original matlab code and the mathematica code I translated are as follows for reference:

Matlab code:

```
function F14 = myfun14(x)
  b = [1/2;1/4;0;1/8;0;0;0;1/16;0;0;0;0;0;0];
  A = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(1);
  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(2);
  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(3);
  0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(4);
  0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(5);
  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(6);
  0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(7);
  0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(8);
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,x(9);
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,x(10);
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,x(11);
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,x(12);
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,x(13);
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,x(14)];
      B = A^(16-15);
      for n=5:50
      B = B + A^(2^n-15)/2^(n-4);
      end
      F14 = (x - b - 1/32 * B * x);


x0 = 0.06*ones(14,1);
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter','TolFun',1e-60,'TolX',1e-60);
[x1,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x0,options);
[x2,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x1,options);
[x3,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x2,options);
[x4,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x3,options);
[x5,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x4,options);
[x,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x5,options);
for t=1:200
[x,fval14] = fsolve(@myfun14,x,options);
end

A = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(1);
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(2);
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(3);
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(4);
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(5);
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(6);
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(7);
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,x(8);
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,x(9);
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,x(10);
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,x(11);
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,x(12);
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,x(13);
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,x(14)];
xfinal = (A)^((10^9)-15)*x;
```

Mathematica code for the function definition part:

```
myfun14[list_] := Module[{b, A, B},
b = Transpose@{{1/2., 1/4., 0., 1/8., 0, 0, 0, 1/16., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0}};
A = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[1]]},
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[2]]},
{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[3]]},
{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[4]]},
{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[5]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[6]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[7]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[8]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[9]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, list[[10]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, list[[11]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, list[[12]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, list[[13]]},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, list[[14]]}};
B = A + Sum[MatrixPower[A, (2^n - 15)]/2.^(n - 4), {n, 5, 50}];
(list - b - 1/32.*B*list)]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do to the companion matrix of a polynomial?

Comment: @J. M. The description of the original problem and code is here, http://jingplusplus.com/2015/06/12/mathpuzzleslotteryproblem/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing `B*list` to `B.list` seems to solve the problem.  Also, I recommend dropping unnecessary decimal points from `myfun14`.  Doing so gives

```
(* {x[1] -> 0.5, x[2] -> 0.273438, x[3] -> 0.0128174, x[4] -> 0.125601, 
    x[5] -> 0.00588754, x[6] -> 0.000275978, x[7] -> 0.0000129365, 
    x[8] -> 0.0625006, x[9] -> 0.00292972, x[10] -> 0.00013733, 
    x[11] -> 6.43736*10^-6, x[12] -> 3.01751*10^-7, 
    x[13] -> 1.41446*10^-8, x[14] -> 6.63028*10^-10} *)
```

**Addendum**

The recently updated code in the Question truly takes forever to run, because `FindRoot` first attempts to evaluate symbolically the gigantic expression created by `myfun14[Array[x, 14]]`.  This can be circumvented by using the option, `Evaluated -> False`.

```
FindRoot[myfun14[Array[x, 14]], Transpose[{Array[x, 14], ConstantArray[6/100, 14]}], 
 Evaluated -> False]
(* {x[1] -> 0.500634, x[2] -> 0.266567, x[3] -> 0.00914348, 
    x[4] -> 0.130162, x[5] -> 0.00916464, x[6] -> 0.00235785, 
    x[7] -> 0.00297105, x[8] -> 0.065152, x[9] -> 0.00401983, 
    x[10] -> 0.00206912, x[11] -> 0.00273191, x[12] -> 0.00231037, 
    x[13] -> 0.00135524, x[14] -> 0.00136153} *)
```

Runtime on my PC is just less than one second.

Comment: Thank you, your method worked. I still have two things not clear : 1. I added those decimal points to let mathematica do numerical computation instead of keeping the rational numbers, but I have made things worse; 2. Although the program seems to be identical with the matlab one, this step gives different and wrong answers compared to matlab, where the correct answer should be approximately {0.5006, 0.2666, 0.0091, 0.1302, 0.0092, 0.0024, 0.0030, 0.0652, 0.0040, 0.0021, 0.0027, 0.0023, 0.0014, 0.0014}. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: @Nick 1) The problem appears to have been `MatrixPower[A, (16 - 15.)]`.  `MatrixPower` expects an integer for its second argument, and `15.` is a real number.  2} I tried different initial guesses and a much higher `WorkingPrecision` for `FindRoot`, but the answer did not change.  My guess is that there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: I have located the typo, I forgot to change the `^` into `MatrixPower` in the definition of `myFun14`. But after changing this, the question returned to its original state: the function again becomes evaluating forever:( I have updated the mathematica code.

Comment: @Nick  Just a guess: replace `2.^(n - 4)` by `2^(n - 4)`.  In general, use rationale numbers, unless there is a good reason not to.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work this time. My guess is that `MatrixPower` is trying to evaluate the power symbolically and then guess numerically using `FindRoot`, while matlab is doing both numerically...

Comment: @Nick  With an easy but less than obvious change, I get `{x[1] -> 0.500634, x[2] -> 0.266567, x[3] -> 0.00914348, 
  x[4] -> 0.130162, x[5] -> 0.00916464, x[6] -> 0.00235785, 
  x[7] -> 0.00297105, x[8] -> 0.065152, x[9] -> 0.00401983, 
  x[10] -> 0.00206912, x[11] -> 0.00273191, x[12] -> 0.00231037, 
  x[13] -> 0.00135524, x[14] -> 0.00136153}}` in `0.9` seconds.  See edit to Answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can also make use of the [undocumented syntax of `FindRoot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273/1871):

```
Clear@myfun14; 
myfun14[list_] := 
 Module[{b, A, B}, 
  b = Transpose@{{1/2, 1/4, 0, 1/8, 0, 0, 0, 1/16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
  A = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1., 13], -1]; A[[All, -1]] = list;
  B = A + Sum[MatrixPower[A, (2^n - 15)]/2.^(n - 4), {n, 5, 50}];
  (list - b - 1/32 B.list)]

FindRoot[myfun14, {ConstantArray[6/100, 14]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.13405, {{0.500634, 0.266567, 0.00914348, 0.130162, 
               0.00916464, 0.00235785, 0.00297105, 0.065152, 0.00401983, 
               0.00206912, 0.00273191, 0.00231037, 0.00135524, 0.00136153}}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be changing the `myfun14[list_]` to `myfun14[list_ /; VectorQ[list, NumberQ]]`, the result can be obtained after a few seconds. Setting a high `AccuracyGoal` is also necessary to get the correct answer for the problem.